# Include figures from publications in thesis (Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 4.0)

Tags: copyright

I would be interest what is common/best practice to include figures from published papers/literature in my thesis (Which will be published open-access). The figures of interest are copyrighted by `(Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 4.0)`.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend a bit on the specific form of "open access" which doesn't have a clear meaning, but is a set of principles and practices. The license on such shared work can be no more restrictive than the original. That is probably the case, but it would be worth checking the specifics. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_access